# how to enable flutter quick fix

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

ctrl + . when i click i get error no code action available,
no quick suggestions are active

```
            const BottomBarItems(
                inActiveItem: Icon(
                  Icons.autorenew,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  size: 28,
                ),
                activeItem: Icon(
                  Icons.autorenew,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 28,
                ),
                itemLabel: 'Page 4',
              ),
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79455 maybe it can fix your issue